# In Gloomhaven, is the leading card chosen for initiative after or before monster cards are revealed

Tags: gloomhaven

I understand that the 2 action cards are chosen before monster cards are revealed, but I'm confused about whether leading cards are chosen before monster cards are revealed.

I saw a video that states that the player chooses their leading card before monster cards are revealed, however the wording in the rulebook makes it sound like the leading card is chosen after the monster card is revealed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The rule is a bit ambiguous, but the leading card is selected in card selection and only revealed in initiative phase.

Rules:(emphasis theirs)

Select cards:

> Of the two cards, one should be selected as the **leading card,** which will determine the player's order of imitative for the round

Determine initiative:

> After players have either selected their two action cards or declared a long rest, the players reveal a monster ability card for each type of monster that has at least one figure currently on the map. In addition, each player not taking a long rest reveals his or her **leading card** for the round.

This means when you pick which two cards to play, you also decide which card will be leading at that time, then player leading and monster cards are revealed at the same time.

Answer (score 5):

Your leading card must be chosen before the monster cards are revealed.  Then determine the initiative order by comparing the initiative values on all player leader cards and all monster cards.

From the rules, pg 18 - Determining Initiative

> After players have either selected their two action cards or declared a long rest, the players reveal a monster ability card for each type of monster that has at least one  gure currently on the map. In addition, each player not taking a long rest reveals his or her selected cards for the round, placing their leading card on top so that its initiative value is visible.
>
> Initiative order is determined by comparing the initiative  values on all played monster ability cards and all of the players’ leading cards. Whoever has the lowest initiative value takes their turn  first, then the next highest, and so on until every figure on the board has acted.

Remember, when its gets to your turn, the leading card designation is no longer significant.

You can play the top or bottom action of either of your two cards first.  Then you play the other action on the other card.

Comment: In my playgroup, we 1. choose our cards, 2. reveal our leading card/initiative, 3. reveal monster abilities/initiative 4. compare initiative. This seems to make sense and keeps all of us players honest

Comment: @user30903 Yes, technically the rules call for revealing monster and leading cards together, though in practice doing them in either order, as long as they don't influence eachother shouldn't matter.

Comment: In my group we just reveal all of our cards with the leading card on top (so on the bottom of the stack while it's face down and I'm waiting for everyone else to figure out what they are doing) then reveal the monster cards ...